# Array de ponteiros com struct

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, alocação

Eu estou tentando atribuir 3 nomes ao um vetor de string dentro de uma struct, e usando ponteiros para referencia a struct alocada dinamicamente, e depois imprimir e inverte-la seguidamente numa estrutura de repetição, mas ao tentar imprimi-la não é retornado nada.

**String a ser imprimida**

```
printf("%s\n",*(*p).vet[1]); Ana
printf("%s\n",*(*p).vet[2]); Bia 
printf("%s\n",*(*p).vet[3]); Lia
```

**String Invertida**

```
   printf("%c\n",*(*q).vet[1]); a+n+A 
   printf("%c\n",*(*q).vet[2]); a+i+B
   printf("%c\n",*(*q).vet[3]); a+i+L
```

**Código**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct elemento *ponteiro;


struct elemento
{
    int chave;
    char vet[100][4];
    ponteiro prox;
};



main()
{
ponteiro p,prim,h,q;
int i;

prim=NULL;
p=(ponteiro) malloc(4*sizeof(struct elemento));
h=p;
(*p).chave=1;
*(*p).vet[1]="Ana";
*(*p).vet[2]="Bia";
*(*p).vet[3]="Lia";
printf("%s\n",*(*p).vet[1]);
printf("%s\n",*(*p).vet[2]);
printf("%s\n",*(*p).vet[3]);


for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   q=(ponteiro)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
   *(*q).vet[1]=*(*p).vet[1]+*(*p).vet[1,4-i];
   *(*q).vet[2]=*(*p).vet[2]+*(*p).vet[2,4-i];
   *(*q).vet[3]=*(*p).vet[3]+*(*p).vet[3,4-i];

   printf("%c\n",*(*q).vet[1]);
   printf("%c\n",*(*q).vet[2]);
   printf("%c\n",*(*q).vet[3]);
   p=q;
}




}
```

Comment: O problema está maioritariamente na notação usada nos ponteiros e printfs. Mas ainda não percebi exatamente qual o objetivo do exercicio. É imprimir várias string ao contrário ? E tem de ser com ponteiros ?

Comment: imprimir 3 strings e depois inverte-las  usando ponteiros só isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A notação de ponteiros usada não está correta em alguns locais, de acordo com o tipo declarado. Quando faz:

```
*(*p).vet[1]="Ana";
```

Já tem vários problemas, pois `vet` é um array de strings, então `vet[1]` é uma string, logo tem um `*` a mais no inicio. No entanto atribuição de strings em C é feito com [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) e o `(*p).` pode ser simplificado para `p->`. Utilizando tudo isso que mencionei essa instrução ficaria:

```
strcpy(p->vet[1], "Ana");
```

Na atribuição do ponteiro `q` também tem o mesmo problema, e a declaração das strings `vet[100][4]` certamente ficou ao contrário pois acabou por declarar `100` strings de tamanho `4`.

Acabou por complicar bastante na solução mesmo com a restrição de usar ponteiros. Se o objetivo é inverter um array de 3 strings utilizando ponteiros, então apenas isto é suficiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//função de inversão utilizando ponteiros
void inverter(char *str){
    int tam = strlen(str), i;
    for (i = 0; i < tam / 2; ++i){
        char temp = *(str + i);
        *(str + i) = *(str + tam - i - 1);
        *(str + tam - i - 1) = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    char strings[4][100];
    strcpy(strings[0], "Ana");
    strcpy(strings[1], "Bia");
    strcpy(strings[2], "Lia");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        inverter(strings[i]);
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/eoxGC9)

Comment: o strcpy(p->vet[1], "Ana"); me ajudou na primeira parte mas o algoritmo tem que ser esse mesmo